# PowerShell, simple timed script delivers unreliable results

Tags: powershell

I´m quite new to PowerShell and just a bit more experienced with programming as such.
The goal of the current excercise our teacher gave us, is basically to code a simple crossroads traffic light.

I use Windows Forms to display labels, that change colors.
Now I coded a button, that is supposed to run through the traffic light "phases" once.
Thanks to prior experiences I went with the method to have a incrementing variable and a Function that checks the value of said variable.

But the colors turn the intended way once every 4 tries or so, without a recognizable logic to it.
Am I missing something basic in the way PS reads code and the timing thereof?

Button, supposed to reset the variable, then increment it, then call the function. Due to the Write-Host I can at lease say that the variable does count to 4 as intended

```
$Button1              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button;
$Button1.Location     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,100);
$Button1.Text         = "Next Phase";
$Window.Controls.Add($Button1);
$Button1.Add_Click({
    #Set Phase 0, then increment & update Function Phase
    $current_phase = 0;
    Do {
        $current_phase++;
        Write-Host $current_phase;
        Phase_update;
        
    } Until($current_phase -gt 3)
```

Two of the functions minus some of the color changes, intended to change the colors and then wait a while

```
Function Phase_update
{
    #Phase A
    if ( $current_phase -eq 1 ) 
    {
        $LightTop.ForeColor   = 'red';
    }
    #Phase B
    elseif ( $current_phase -eq 2 ) 
    {
        $LightTop.ForeColor   = 'green'
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
}
# Show Form
[void]$Window.ShowDialog()
```

Thanks in advance for any input, problem specific and in general

Comment: Function `Phase_update` should be defined before using it. We also do not see where you defined variable `$current_phase` and it is likely that inside the function and click handler it is unknown (therefore becomes local to the script block) if you do not scope it with `$script:current_phase`. As sidenote, PowerShell does not need the `;` as line ending like C#. You would only use that to write two different commands in the same line of code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
The variable should be ok. I defined it right in the beginning outside of any functions as
`[int]$current_phase = 0;`.
But I´ll check for any possible scope problems anyhow, thx.

And makes sense to plase the function before it´s calling. I switch that around in any case.
€: Due to Write-Host I can at least see that the $current_phase variable counts through to 4 as intended in the console.

Comment: I would recommend adding a parameter to the `Phase_update` function, something like `Function Phase_update ([int]$current_phase) {..}` and send that parameter in the Click handler: `Phase_update $current_phase`. That way you can always be sure the function uses the value that is sent to it without relying on script-scoped variables.

Comment: Thanks for the help. At least I cleaned up my script and learned something new.
What seemed to solve it in the end, was to use $Window.Refresh() after each color change. That brought the desired changes in line.